# Volume of the bounded by the region $z=9-x^2-y^2$ and the plane $z=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I have to find the volume bounded by the equations $z=9-x^2-y^2$ and $z=0$, but I do not know how it is supposed to be done correctly.
I have right now:

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 (9-r^2)rdrd\phi = \frac{243}{2}\pi$

But I do not know if this is correct or if it is supposed to be done in this way.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your setup looks fine, but you got one too many factors of $3$ in your answer, it should be $\frac{81\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was actually calculating $3\int_V dV$, that is why there is a factor of 3 in there. But I thought to use another methode where you circle around the y-axis for $y=9-x^2$ for $0\leq x\leq 3$, So $2\pi \int_0^3 (9-x^2) dx$ that gives me a volume of $36\pi$. Why are these answers different?

Comment: Because for that second one, it's like you're finding the area and then making a cylinder of length $2\pi$ out of it, instead of rotating it around the axis which gives a much smaller volume.

Comment: Ah yes, I had to use the formula $Vol = \pi\int_0^9 (9-x) dx = \frac{81}{2} \pi$ (with the inverse function). Now the values do match. Thanks for the help sir.

Comment: At z=0, $x^2+y^2=9$ is a circle with radius 3 and area $\pi \cdot 3^2$. at z=9 we have $x^2+y^2=0$ that is we have a point. so you have a cone with base area $9\pi$ and height= 9 so it's volume is $v=\frac12 \times 9\times (9\pi)=\frac{81\pi}2$

Comment: @sirous, first, this example is not a cone but a paraboloid, and second, that's not the formula for a cone.  In $3d$, it's $\frac{1}{3}$ base x height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates, the computation of that volume becomes$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^9\int_0^{\sqrt{9-z}}r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{81\pi}2.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help sir.